# Как сделать чтобы все собиралось в один общий список

Tags: python-3.x, ооп

Как сделать чтобы все собиралось в один общий список

```
class GostJobs(CreateConfig):
    def get_curl(self):
        config = self.get_curl()
        l = config.get('dc').split(' ')[0]
        print(l)
        my_list = []
        print(my_list.append(l))
```

При каждом запросе получается отдельная строка

На выходе получается

```
(dc05)
None
(dc05)
None
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы все собралось в один список

```
[(dc05),(dc05),(dc05)]
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести воспроизводимый пример? Из очевидных ошибок - 1) вы в функции каждый раз задаете `my_list = []` как пустой список, что противоречит идее накопления значений в нем, 2) печатать `print(my_list.append(l))` бессмысленно, т.к. метод `.append(l)` всегда возвращает None.

Comment: Вот где проблема. Вы в функции каждый раз задаете my_list = [] как пустой список, что противоречит идее накопления значений в нем. Вопрос решен. Спасибо